# How to load contents of multiple files in particular order with Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am using JS/AJAX to display the contents of multiple files on a page. The files are dynamically generated, and are loaded using a for-loop. There is one file that contains metadata for the set, including how many other files need to be loaded. The other files have a number in the filename, and I load them by requesting "file_[loop_index].json".

The problem is, the amount of data in each json file is arbitrary as well, and the AJAX calls will complete in the order of smallest file first. I want to display the data in order based on the name, rather than the size.

Here is a stripped-down example, suppose we want to display the contents of a book:

```
function get(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    req.send();
  });
}

get('toc.json').then(function(response) {
  chapters = JSON.parse(response)["chapters"];
  return chapters;
}).then(function(levels) {
  for (i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      get("chap".concat(i,".json")).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

  })
  }(i));
  }
  });
```

toc.json:

```
{ "chapters": 2 }
```

chap0.json:

```
{ "text" : "00000" }
```

chap1.json:

```
{ "text" : "1" }
```

The result will be:

```
{ "text" : "1" }
{ "text" : "00000" }
```

Where as if I were to switch the number of characters in each file, the result would be:

```
{ "text" : "0" }
{ "text" : "11111" }
```

I want to print the line with "0"'s before the line with "1"'s regardless of each file size.

I cannot use async/await, as my page must work in IE11 and it does not support arrow functions.

The solution I thought of was to store the contents in an array, return that from the for-loop, and display the contents, i.e.:

Attempted Solution:

```
var tempArray = [];

function get(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      } else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    req.send();
  });
}

get('toc.json').then(function(response) {
  chapters = JSON.parse(response)["chapters"];
  return chapters;
}).then(function(levels) {
  for (i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      get("chap".concat(i, ".json")).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        tempArray[i] = response;

      })
    }(i));
  }
  return tempArray;
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

);
```

But the final console.log(response) yields:

```
Array[]
```

I suppose this fails because the promise sequence is proceeding past the for-loop section before the actual AJAX calls complete. If I could figure out how to make it wait for them to finish, I would be there, but at the moment I am stumped.

Another solution that could work under other circumstances is to dynamically generate part of the html, and update the correct elements with the corresponding file contents. Unfortunately this is not an option for my particular use-case.

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: If you really need then loaded in a particular order, then you don't want to use asynchronous requests. Use synchronous requests instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: @MikeFurlender are you really recommending synchronous AJAX? As that very article you linked to mentions, several major browsers have already deprecated it due to the poor user experience it creates, so there's a high chance it'll be removed in future. That page explicitly says "Developers are recommended to move away from the API." Chrome isn't mentioned there but they've deprecated it as well. Apart from creating a bad UX, it can't be relied on (in the medium term) either.

Comment: @MikeFurlender I recommend **against** ever using a synchronous request.  It will make the browser unresponsive.

Comment: I did not realize that synchronous XMLHttpRequests are blocking. Good to know. In that case, pass the order index along to the ajax request, and write the response to an object using the order index as the key. When all the promises resolve combine the values in the object using the keys to enforce order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bending over backwards to use promises. Why not just have the names in an array and have one function doing the getting, update the counter and call the function again?

```
var listOfFiles=["fileList.txt”],
    cnt=0, 
    oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

function reqListener () {
  if (listOfFiles[0]=="fileList.txt") {
    listOfFiles = this.responseText.split(",");
  }
  else { 
    processFile(this.responseText);
    cnt++;
  }
  getFile();
}

oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
function getFile() { 
  if (cnt >= listOfFiles.length) return; 
  oReq.open("GET", listOfFiles[cnt]);
  oReq.send(); 
} 
getFile();
```

Comment: I am currently trying to adapt this answer to see if it will work for me. The main problem is that the number of files in listOfFiles can change, and I am currently using an AJAX call to obtain that list before beginning to loop over the data files. Do you have any suggestion for how you would handle that?

Comment: I had to tweak this a bit more to get it to work, in particular I had to rename "ListOfFiles" to "fileList", not sure if that is what you meant or not. But once I got that figured out, it did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (XHR removed from the example, but Promises still used).

```
function getTOC() {
  var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
    chapters: 2,
  });
  return Promise.resolve(jsonStr);
}

function getChapter(i) {
  return Promise.resolve("chapter " + i);
}

getTOC()
  .then(function(response) {
    var chapters = JSON.parse(response)["chapters"];
    return chapters;
  })
  .then(function(chapters) {
    var promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
      promises.push(getChapter(i));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of results, ordered as expected
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Comment: This would probably work, except I realized since posting this question that promises/promise.all are not supported by IE11, which I mentioned I need to be able to run on.